# SSRS RS.exe migrating reports / datasets in wrong order

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, rs.exe

I am using RS.exe to migrate all SSRS content from one server (SQL Server 2008) to another (SQL 2012).  It is moving everything in a mixed order which is causing items to be not migrated.  Eg a Report is migrated before the dataset or datasource.  A report in a subfolder is migrated before the sub folder is created which triggers an error.

```
rs.exe -i ssrs_migration.rss -e Mgmt2010 -s http://OLDSERVER/ReportServer -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -v ts="http://NEWSERVER/ReportServer" -v tu="USERNAME" -v tp="PASSWORD"
-v security="True" >  e:\rs.exe\rs_output.txt
```

All content should be migrated but its not due to sub folders missing which means the report / datasource etc can't be copied across. It also means reports are not linked to a datasource as they were copied over after the report.

Comment: Personally, when we migrated from SQL Server 2008 to 2012, I found it easier to restore the existing ReportServer database to the 2012 instance, and then used the Reporting Services Configuration Manager to upgrade the database, restore the keys and remove the old server from the scale-out deployment.

Comment: I think i might have to do that.  I liked the idea of using RS.exe so i could duel run for a short while.

Comment: Restoring a backup of your database dioesn't take then old one offline if it's on a new instance.